# need guide with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site on localhost xampp with virtualname mysite.com

I am trying to make the URLs simpler with the following code but its not working.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule    ^$       index.php
RewriteRule    ^home$   index.php
```

The above code works but its hard coded. So if I replace home with `^.*$` site assets gets missing. CSS etc doesn't work.

What I want is a rule that simply gives me everything after the domain so i can on backend use those and shows specific page.

```
mysite.com -gets- 
mysite.com/ -gets- /
mysite.com/home -gets- home
mysite.com/products/abc -gets- products/abc
mysite.com/products/used/xyz -gets- products/used/xyz
```

please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

Above code gives everything in the URL to index.php file.

If you want to use it for every URL except that is not ending with "png","jpg","css","js","gif" you can use :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.js$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

Comment: thanks 4 the reply copied ur code. when i go to `mysite.com/products/abc` the css stops working.

Comment: tried both. assets doesn't work, any idea on this plz? If there is a slash after `mysite.com/abc/` the slash breaks the assets

Comment: Actually second code is not replacing assets to any other thing. Can you check your assets' url there might be problems in there. If there are not any problems with assets' url you might want to use it as your last chance : 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,NC]

Comment: Okay, I am using relative path and the above behaviors still occurs. I have put absolute path and it works fine. I think I'll have to go absolute for now.

Comment: @Bsienn You don't need 5 different rules just to omit the assets. That's a lot of unnecessary code. you can combine them all in to one. `!\.(png|jpe?g|css|gif|js)$`

Comment: @PanamaJack Great tip. I'll modify the rules as you suggested. Thanks a lot for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

To get that specific uri you'll actually need to use php to get it instead of only having a mod_rewrite - note: you'll have to set up mod rewrite to get the right format.

if you want the uri in an array you can use `mixed parse_url ( string $url [, int $component = -1 ] )`

from PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

> This function parses a URL and returns an associative array containing any of the various components of the URL that are present.
>
> This function is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts. Partial URLs are also accepted, parse_url() tries its best to parse them correctly.

or if you want the entire thing use php server variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`